# Right Align String NumberFormat in Java

Tags: java, string, number-formatting, right-align

I need to right align an input string of digits with a mask using plus symbols.

For example:

```
    String input = "893";
    String mask = "&&&&&&";
```

should return

```
    String output = "+++893";
```

I'm very confused on how to implement this with NumberFormat and or DecimalFormat as I haven't used them before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if the mask is shorter than the input? Do you truncate or ignore?

Comment: The I would ignore. But I already check for that.

Comment: What about `String.format("%-6d", input)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use DeciamlFormat you could use:

```
int input = 893;
DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("000000"); //as many palces as you need
String output = decFormat.format(input);
```

And then replace all leading zeros with + sign.

```
String.format("%06d", input); //also gives you leading zeros
```

You still have to check if the output is too long, if you always want 6 places.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: If the length of the mask is greater than the length of the input, take the difference and add that many plus signs to the front of the input.

Comment: Although I don't get the point of the mask then. You could simply have a desired length

Comment: Yeah that was my first idea but I just wanted to ask if there was a more elegant way using NumberFormat.

Comment: the mask will also be part of the input.